# Powershell v2 and PowerShell v3 Object handling

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

When I create object in powershell v2 i am unable to access powershell member properties, which will flowlesly works with PowerShell V3.  e.g. if i create below object in v3,

```powershell
$Services = @();
$item = @{};
$item.Name = "ServiceName";
$item.Action = 2;
$item.ActionTime = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
$obj = New-Object PSObject -Property $item;
$Services = $Services + $obj
```

I can access $services.Action which will be 2, whether on PowerShell v2 it will be blank.

Any help?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually because you are wrapping the object in an array.

In v2, to get all of the `Action` properties of an array of objects, you would do something like this:

```powershell
$Services | ForEach-Object { $_.Action }
# or
$Services | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Action
```

In PowerShell v3, this is no longer necessary:

```powershell
$Services.Action
```

Will automatically perform the same operation.

[New V3 Language Features](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/06/14/new-v3-language-features.aspx)

Further, if you had just done `$obj.Action` it would have worked in v2 as well (for just that one object).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if you want to list all actions or just for a particular index, you can use:

```
$Services | Select -ExpandProperty Action
```

or (in the case of the first service):

```
$Services[0].Action
```